# How to open User data detail when clicked on each User name in a TAB

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of users. List of users is appearing on the left side, and when clicked on a specific user, it should open that users detailed data.

Little Video Explanation

https://www.loom.com/share/d46c72d3157f4c0b8f41b75c6b4eb83a?sid=6306b0f1-5312-469e-8fe1-8a04ac5236df

I am using While loop for this. I am able to print the users list with while loop but i don't know how to open that clicked user detail on the right side of container.

As right side of container isn't coming in the while loop, but when i try to bring it in, the design gets messed. How to bring that right side in while loop, so when ID's gets matched, i can open User details.

Like i am matching `data-user-id="<?php echo $row['inv_id'];?>">` on both left and rigth side

Left Side, Printing Users Details

```
<div class="app-chat">
                      <ul class="chat-users" style="height: calc(100vh - 400px)" data-simplebar="">
                        <?php
                        $InvMeta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM investors_meta ORDER BY 1 DESC");
                        if ($_SESSION['useradmin']=='Investor') {
                          $InvMeta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM investors_meta WHERE inv_id = ".$_SESSION['uid']." ORDER BY 1 DESC");
                        }
                        $S_NO = 0;
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($InvMeta)){

                          $FetchInvData     = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$row['inv_id']);
                          $inv              = mysqli_fetch_assoc($FetchInvData);
                          
                        $S_NO++;
                        ?>
                        <li>
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="px-4 py-3 bg-hover-light-black d-flex align-items-center chat-user bg-light" id="chat_user_1" data-user-id="<?php echo $row['inv_id'];?>">
                            <span class="position-relative">
                              <img src="assets/dist/images/profile/user-4.jpg" alt="user-4" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-circle">
                            </span>
                            <div class="ms-6 d-inline-block w-75">
                              <h6 class="mb-1 fw-semibold chat-title" data-username="James Anderson"><?php echo $inv['full_name'];?></h6>
                              <span class="fs-2 text-body-color d-block"><?php echo $inv['mobile'];?>, <?php echo $inv['userEmail'];?></span>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
```

Right Side Where when clicked, user detailed data should be open

```
<div class="w-100">
                  <div class="chat-container h-100 w-100">
                    <div class="chat-box-inner-part h-100">
                      <div class="chatting-box app-email-chatting-box">
                        <div class="p-9 py-3 border-bottom chat-meta-user d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                          <h5 class="text-dark mb-0 fw-semibold">Contact Details</h5>
                          <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <li class="d-lg-none d-block">
                              <a class="text-dark back-btn px-2 fs-5 bg-hover-primary nav-icon-hover position-relative z-index-5" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="ti ti-arrow-left"></i>
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="position-relative" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Edit">
                              <a class="d-block text-dark px-2 fs-5 bg-hover-primary nav-icon-hover position-relative z-index-5" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="ti ti-pencil"></i>
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="position-relative" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Delete">
                              <a class="text-dark px-2 fs-5 bg-hover-primary nav-icon-hover position-relative z-index-5" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="ti ti-trash"></i>
                              </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="position-relative overflow-hidden">
                          <div class="position-relative">
                            <div class="chat-box p-9" style="height: calc(100vh - 428px)" data-simplebar="">
                            
                              <div class="chat-list chat active-chat" data-user-id="<?php echo $row['inv_id'];?>">
                                <div class="hstack align-items-start mb-7 pb-1 align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
                                    <img src="assets/dist/images/profile/user-4.jpg" alt="user4" width="72" height="72" class="rounded-circle">
                                    <div>
                                      <h6 class="fw-semibold fs-4 mb-0">Dr. Bonnie Barstow </h6>
                                      <p class="mb-0">Sales Manager</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0">Digital Arc Pvt. Ltd.</p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-4 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Phone number</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">+1 (203) 3458</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-8 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Email address</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">alexandra@modernize.com</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-12 mb-9">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Address</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">312, Imperical Arc, New western corner</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-4 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">City</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">New York</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-8 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Country</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">United Stats</h6>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="border-bottom pb-7 mb-4">
                                  <p class="mb-2 fs-2">Notes</p>
                                  <p class="mb-3 text-dark"> 
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque bibendum 
                                    hendrerit lobortis. Nullam ut lacus eros. Sed at luctus urna, eu fermentum diam. 
                                    In et tristique mauris.
                                  </p>
                                  <p class="mb-0 text-dark">Ut id ornare metus, sed auctor enim. Pellentesque nisi magna, laoreet a augue eget, tempor volutpat diam.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
                                  <button class="btn btn-primary fs-2">Edit</button>
                                  <button class="btn btn-danger fs-2">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You'll need some Javascript and possible AJAX. What have you researched and tried so far? Handle the click on the link using JS, and write some code to fetch and populate the necessary detail into a target element in the other part of the page. You may find that a templating engine is helpful for this, too, to make it easier to put the data into your layout in the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

Use another while loop where the user details are showing.

```
<div class="position-relative overflow-hidden">
                          <div class="position-relative">
                            <div class="chat-box p-9" style="height: calc(100vh - 428px)" data-simplebar="">
                            <?php
                            $InvMeta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM investors_meta ORDER BY 1 DESC");
                            if ($_SESSION['useradmin']=='Investor') {
                              $InvMeta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM investors_meta WHERE inv_id = ".$_SESSION['uid']." ORDER BY 1 DESC");
                            }
                            $S_NO = 0;
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($InvMeta)){

                              $FetchInvData     = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$row['inv_id']);
                              $inv              = mysqli_fetch_assoc($FetchInvData);
                              
                            $S_NO++;
                            ?>
                              <div class="chat-list chat active-chat" data-user-id="<?php echo $row['inv_id'];?>">
                                <div class="hstack align-items-start mb-7 pb-1 align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
                                    <img src="assets/dist/images/profile/user-4.jpg" alt="user4" width="72" height="72" class="rounded-circle">
                                    <div>
                                      <h6 class="fw-semibold fs-4 mb-0"><?php echo $inv['full_name'];?> </h6>
                                      <p class="mb-0">Sales Manager</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0">Digital Arc Pvt. Ltd.</p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-4 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Phone number</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">+1 (203) 3458</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-8 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Email address</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">alexandra@modernize.com</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-12 mb-9">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Address</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">312, Imperical Arc, New western corner</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-4 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">City</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">New York</h6>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-8 mb-7">
                                    <p class="mb-1 fs-2">Country</p>
                                    <h6 class="fw-semibold mb-0">United Stats</h6>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="border-bottom pb-7 mb-4">
                                  <p class="mb-2 fs-2">Notes</p>
                                  <p class="mb-3 text-dark"> 
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque bibendum 
                                    hendrerit lobortis. Nullam ut lacus eros. Sed at luctus urna, eu fermentum diam. 
                                    In et tristique mauris.
                                  </p>
                                  <p class="mb-0 text-dark">Ut id ornare metus, sed auctor enim. Pellentesque nisi magna, laoreet a augue eget, tempor volutpat diam.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
                                  <button class="btn btn-primary fs-2">Edit</button>
                                  <button class="btn btn-danger fs-2">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```